# Will google gsutil partially upload a file?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

As for one file, will Google gsutil get it partially uploaded before any error happens? Or if there are any errors in the middle of uploading, it will make the whole uploading fail, thus no incomplete contents will be upload onto Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an error occurs in the middle of a transfer, no incomplete file will be present in Google Cloud Storage.

gsutil uses the [Resumable Upload](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#resumable) protocol. Until a resumable upload is finalized, the contents of the object being written are not present in your bucket.